# redirect old url to new url in htaccess download page

Tags: .htaccess

i have mp3 script and and i have old url like 
`domain.com/download/9UN_umrICqw/stomody.html`
and now i want to redirect like that
`domain.com/downloads/9UN_umrICqw/stomody.html`
actually now i m running `domain.com/downloads/9UN_umrICqw/stomody.html`  but i have old url without s in download i mean `domain.com/download/9UN_umrICqw/stomody.html` so i want to redirect them to new one i m getting 404 error when user visit `download/` so i want to redirect with `downloads/` when any user visit actually i have indexing in google without s `download/` so that is reason i hope guys you uderstand my question

just want to add downloads before it is download so how i can redirect please help me here is .htaccess code

```
RewriteRule ^downloads/(.*)/(.*)\.html?$ search.php?id=$1&key=$2
```

Comment: still waiting no answer ?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect `/download/` and its sub-uris to `/downloads/` you can simply use  `Redirect`

```
Redirect 301 /download/ /downloads/
```